# Recovering incomplete iCloud backup?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

I recently took a back up of my iPhone 11 Pro Max and assumed the backup was done, so erased the content.

When it came time to recover my data to my new phone (iPhone 14 Pro Max with iOS 17), the backup wasn't available because it was incomplete.

I assumed that the backup was done when I saw the 360GB beside the backup at the time. Below is a screenshot of the backup record as seen through my new phone's settings. I don't have access to my old phone anymore as I have sold it.

[image]

Is there anyone who has experienced this and what was your solution?

Comment: -Phone's model (14 pro max) operating system? iOs17 
- I learned the back up was incomplete after trying to restore the 14 pro max
The error message was it wasn’t showing the backup. I backed up from an 11 pro max and assumed the backup was done when I saw the 360GB beside the backup

Comment: The screenshot came from the new phone. I sold the old one

Comment: That's a fairly large backup even though incomplete. Were your photos, contacts, calendar, notes, etc. synched to iCloud in your old iPhone? If so, you should at least be able to recover / resynch those to your new iPhone simply by signing in with the same Apple ID as before and turning on iCloud.